# Images downloaded from scrapy smaller than expected (jpegs) or unreadable (tifs)

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scrapy

I'm not sure how best to pose this question. I'm new to both python and scrapy.

Essentially, the files I download using my scrapy script do not match the files I would download manually. All the files (even the smallest jpeg image) is reduced in size. When I open the images in Photoshop, the 'tif' files are in an unrecognizable format. The jpegs open fine. Further, the files I download are downloaded as grayscale files, and the ones my scrapy script pulls are RGB.

As far as I can tell the documentation on the [image_pipeline](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html) is pretty much all there is for processing images with scrapy, but it does mention it uses the pillow library for processing.

My thinking is that it's doing something under the hood by default to adjust the images &| limit the size of the downloads. But I don't know what that could be or how to disable it. I'd like to download the images 'as is', i.e., with as little (read: none) processing as possible.

If it helps, below are the relevant files. I've omitted some of the code for my spider for brevity, the omitted parts only relate to scraping metadata such as titles and reference numbers.

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class FsaImageData(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    digital_id = scrapy.Field()
    source_url = scrapy.Field()
    project = scrapy.Field()
    call_nums = scrapy.Field()
    next_url = scrapy.Field()
    image_sizes = scrapy.Field()
    image_names = scrapy.Field()

    # fields also used to download.
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    image = scrapy.Field()
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.pipelines.images import ImagesPipeline

class GetFsaImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for i,url in enumerate(item['image_urls']):
            image_name = item['image_names'][i]
            yield scrapy.Request(url, meta={'image_name': image_name})

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return request.meta['image_name']
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'LOC_FSA_1935'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['LOC_FSA_1935.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'LOC_FSA_1935.spiders'

# Files Pipeline:
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'LOC_FSA_1935.pipelines.GetFsaImagesPipeline':1}
IMAGES_STORE = '/Volumes/FSA_IMAGES/1935/'

# Probably just for testing for now:
IMAGES_EXPIRES = 0

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

# AUTOTHROTTLE (BE NICE!!)
AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
```

**spider.py**

```
import scrapy
from LOC_FSA_1935.items import FsaImageData
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin


class FSA_1935_Spider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "fsa1935"
    start_urls = [ 'http://www.loc.gov/pictures/' ]

    custom_settings = {
            'FEED_FORMAT':'csv',
            # TODO: include below in FINAL version of spider!
             #'LOG_FILE':'.fsa1935.log',
             #'LOG_STDOUT':'True',
            }


    def parse(self, response):
        # navigate to search results page 1
        results = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find('div',
              class_='results_item ')
        return scrapy.Request(url=urljoin(response.url, results.a['href']),
                callback=self.parseFirst )


    def parseFirst(self, response):
        # navigate to first image returned by FSA searched
        detail = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml').find('a',
                text='View Larger').parent
        return scrapy.Request(url=urljoin(response.url, detail.a['href']),
                callback=self.parsePage )


    def parsePage(self, response):
        # pull metadata and image_urls for each page entry in the search,
        # pass url to next entry in search to next iteration
        data = FsaImageData()
        ex_msg = ('EXCEPTION: Unable to gather {} for {}.'
                     '\n\tException Type: {}:{}')

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
        # get digital_id, project, & source_url
        description = soup.find('div', {'id':'description'} )
        if description != None:
            # get image_urls, _sizes, and _names:
            img_urls = []
            img_sizes = []
            img_names = []
            for img in description.find_all(
                    'a', text=re.compile('JPEG|TIFF \([0-9.a-zA-Z]*\)')):
                img_urls.append(urljoin( response.url, img['href']))
                img_sizes.append(img.get_text())
                img_names.append(img['href'].split('/')[-1])

            data['image_urls'] = img_urls
            data['image_sizes'] = img_sizes
            data['image_names'] = img_names
        else:
            print( 'WARNING: Item description does not exist!' )
        # scape image_data:
        yield data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out and solved my own issue! I poked around in the source code for the ImagesPipeline and discovered that by default, scrapy uses a method `convert_images` when it calls `get_images`. `convert_images` was the issue, as it converts both the filetype and colorspace for non-jpeg and bmp images.

I re-wrote `get_images` to handle both the tiff and jpeg formats I was interested in scraping:

```
def get_images(self, response, request, info):
    path = self.file_path(request, response=response, info=info)
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.body))
    buf = BytesIO()

    ext = response.url.split('.')[-1]
    if ext == 'tif':
        exif = image.tag_v2
        image.save(buf, 'TIFF', tiffinfo=exif)
    else:
        image.save(buf, 'JPEG')

    yield path, image, buf
```

Hope that helps others in the future!